# Scala code to insert a row into Hbase

Tags: scala

Below is a case class and a companion object with a method `putRecord` which adds a new row into Hbase using [Put API](https://hbase.apache.org/1.1/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put.html). This code has some repetitive parts. Is there a way to abstract away the repetitive code

```
case class HbaseRow(_id: Option[String], field1: Option[Array[String]], field2: Option[Array[String]], field3: Option[String], field4: Option[Long])

object HbaseRow {
    def putRecord(row: HbaseRow): Put = {
        val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(row._id.get))

        def addColumn[T](columnName: String,value: T): Put = {
          val columnFamily:Array[Byte] = Bytes.toBytes("cf")
          val col: Array[Byte] = Bytes.toBytes(columnName)
          // Repetative, almost same method call but for different types
          value match {
            case v: String => put.addColumn(columnFamily, col,Bytes.toBytes(v)) 
            case v: Long => put.addColumn(columnFamily, col,Bytes.toBytes(v))
            case v: Boolean => put.addColumn(columnFamily, col,Bytes.toBytes(v))
            case v: Array[String] => put.addColumn(columnFamily, col,Bytes.toBytes(v.mkString(",")))
          }
        }

        //Repetitive will be tedious as columns increase.
        row.field1.map(value => addColumn[Array[String]]("f1",value.mkString(","))) 
        row.field2.map(value => addColumn[Array[String]]("f2",value.mkString(",")))
        row.field3.map(value => addColumn[String]("f3",value))
        row.field4.map(value => addColumn[Long]("f4",value))

        put
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `def addColumn` you can extract bytes and then add them to `put`:

```scala
val bytes = value match {
  case v: String => Bytes.toBytes(v)
  case v: Long => Bytes.toBytes(v)
  case v: Boolean => Bytes.toBytes(v)
  case v: Array[String] => Bytes.toBytes(v.mkString(","))
}
put.addColumn(columnFamily, col, bytes)
```

I'm not sure that Scala can check generic types in pattern matching, so `Array[String]` may be checked only for class `Array`. If it is than the compiler will warn you.

2nd, if you don't use result, you can use `foreach` instead of `map`.

3rd `value.mkString(",")` is `String` so value type is also `String`, not `Array[String]`. Of course you can simple declare `def addColumn(columnName: String, value: Any)`, or first create `sealed trait ColumnValue` and use `def addColumn(columnName: String, value: ColumnValue)`.

According to 3rd, you can use:

```scala
List("f1" -> row.field1, ..., "f4" -> row.field4).foreach {
  // you can use only 2nd case if you handle `Array` in `def addColumn`
  case (columnName, field: Array[_]) => addColumn(columnName, field.mkString(","))
  case (columnName, field) => addColumn(columnName, field)
}
```